# How is time calculated when training a neural network in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I saved the training performance in a struct 'tr'. Summing up the tr.time values gives much higher results than if I just use the tic toc functionality.

Comment: This could be the total processing time summed across your different processor/GPUs. MATLAB is pretty good about parallelizing computations like this one behind the scenes.